# the translation for culture EN reference and object of type X with name X but that object has been deleted

Tags: ssas, tabular, ssas-tabular

after I try to delete a DAX i get the error:

even after I create a new translation, I can work on it and after a couple of times a get this message again

what can be the cause of that?

thanks

oh i cant post images.. the error is :

> Failed To Save Modification To the server. 'The translations for culture EN references an object of type "X" with name of "X" but that object has been deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Visual Studio to edit your Tabular Model?

Try to export the translations into a .json file, remove all translations from the model, and then import them again, using the .json file.

Alternatively, switch to [Tabular Editor](https://tabulareditor.github.io) - it generally works better than Visual Studio when working on a model that has translations.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when I deleted some columns.

This method worked for me:

1. Export the translation to JSON file
2. Delete translation from the object (change the string from "*my_translation*" to "")
3. Import the JSON file back into the model
4. Delete the object normally